# Optimising conditional code for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, conditional-statements

There are two types of pages I am interested in for Wordpress: pages and posts.

At the top of my posts template, I have some code as following to display varying banner ads:

```
<?php if ( ! is_single() && ! is_search() && ! is_category() && ! is_tag() && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_single() && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>


<?php if ( ! is_single() && ! is_search() && ! is_category() && ! is_tag() && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_single() && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>
```

At the top of my pages template, I have some code as following to display varying banner ads:

```
<?php if ( is_page(1302) && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_page(3651) && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_page(602) && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_page(array(602,3651,1302)) && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() && ! my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>


<?php if ( is_page(1302) && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_page(3651) && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_page(602) && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_page(array(602,3651,1302)) && my_wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
ad code
<?php } ?>
```

All the "ad codes" are different. I would like to move the banner ad to a different place in my theme and have been trying something like:

```
<?php
    if ( is_single() ) {
        get_template_part( 'postads' );
    }
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    if ( is_single() ) {
require("postads.php");
    }
?>
```

With postads.php being a file in my child theme and containing the relevant banner code and conditions as above.

I've been trying both php include and get_template_part to no avail - it simply won't show up (site loads, no ad code).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to neatly optimise this code? I am sure there is a better way!

Comment: You have a question which is almost 4 years old, and you have never taken the time to leave any kind of feedback. If an answer helped to solve your issue, accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it, or post your own solution and accept it

Comment: Apologies I thought the site chose for me. I have fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `global $post;` on top of your postads.php file. The conditional queries are depending on this.

```
<?php
  global $post;

  // your add codes

?>
```